# A modern approach to homotopy theory in $\mathbf{SSet}$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I'm currently trying to understand the basics of homotopy theory for simplicial sets. However, my current sources (Peter Mays "Simplicial objects in algebraic topology" and Kans original "on c.s.s. complexes") are kinda outdated in the sense that, for example, they define the extension condition combinatorically on the set of simplices, instead of via the more modern horn filling condition.

What I'm looking for is a source that uses modern notation, i.e. defines Kan complexes via horn filling conditions, but doesn't take the top down model structure approach (since I want to use this as a motivation on why a model category is defined the way it is).

Comment: Model structures are defined as they are because of the model structures on spaces and chain complexes, moreso than because of that on simplicial sets.

Comment: @Kevin Really? I think I remember having read somewhere, that Model structures were meant to "merge" the theory of cofibrant objects in $\mathbf{Top}$ with the theory of fibrant objects in $\mathbf{sSet}$, or at least something in that vein.

Comment: Ok, in Mark Hoveys "Quillen Model Structures" he states that Quillen tried to put the concepts of cofibrant replacement in $\mathbf{Top}$ and fibrant replacement in $\mathbf{sSet}$ into one coherent theory.

Comment: Hm, OK, Hovey knows better than me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the book *Simplicial homotopy theory* by Goerss and Jardine? They have a 60-pages Chapter 1 on simplicial sets, at the end of which they define the model structure on $\mathsf{sSet}$. IMHO the book is quite good. I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't take the top down model structure approach", but definitions don't fall from the sky and are motivated from topology.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I remeber working with it a few years ago... just picked up a copy from the local library to give it a try.

Comment: Complicated filling arguments were for me easier to find and explain geometrically in the case of cubical sets (with connections). The intuitions are given in the book "Nonabelian Algebraic Topology:.."  advertised at http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html .the main results of which have not been obtained simplicially.  However this book does not deal with the analogues of simplicial groups, so there is still lots to do in this area.

Comment: Dear @Ronnie, once you've lifted the model structure on the category of cubical sets to $\mathbf{Cat}$, I might have a look at your work. 'Til then, please stop trying to pitch your books to me. Najibs recommendation was exactly what I was looking for, yours was'nt even related to my question...